# Coudn't hit the contextroot in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to Spring MVC, trying to develop a small application. 
My problem is when i try to hit the application with
localhost:8080/MyFirstApplication I get an error saying request resource is not available.
However when I change the url-pattern to /forms/*,
I am able to hit the application localhost:8080/MyFirstApplication/forms/loginform.jsp.
I have placed the loginform.jsp in WEB-INF/views/.

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>MyFirstApplication</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>loginform.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Can someone pls pointout what has gone wrong here!

Comment: Can you send us MyFirstApplicationController

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/`. That means that **every** request goes to this servlet.
So, if you didn't define any controller in your app, everything will lead to 404.

Defining a JSP as a welcome file goes completely against the idea of using MVC: a JSP is a view, and a request should always go to a controller, never to a view directly. So my advice is: don't take shortcuts; define a controller.